# How to create more realistic shadows?

Tags: node-editor, transparency, shadows

Obligatory disclaimer: This is my first post on blender.stackexchange so forgive me if my post isn't on par with what's usually asked here.

**Explanation:**

I'm running v.2.80 of Blender currently and I have a video that's already been tracked, and my scene has been set up so that this tile sits on the wall of the building. [image]

However the shadow of the tile doesn't match up with the rest of the scene (which is just the default shadow catcher). I currently have a compositor node set up in another file that I want to use in order to get the following result:

[image]

**So,**

How can I set up the shadow catcher so that only the part of the video that it's casting over will be affected by the compositor node?

**Edit 1:**
The scene has been set up with a Sun, and the world's color has been set to blue those are the only two sources of light. I've tried using a area light instead of global lighting and the results are the same.

Comment: Hi. By "tile", do you mean that you've replaced the wall with a textured plane or something?

Comment: Oh, now I understand what your talking about, I was confused by the fact that you had a separate image of the wall texture.  :)   I think that all you have to do is change the lighting your using in your 3D scene.  the i believe that the problem is that your shadow isn't tinged blue, so maybe add blue sky lighting?

Comment: The sky lighting in the scene is actually blue already, but that doesn't effect that shadow catcher. Also, notice the difference in contrast between the parts of the wall that are casted in shadow and those that are not, there's clear highlights, mids, and shadows on one, and not another, which is why I have the node tree that I want to use.

Comment: You might be interested in [this method](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/140477/30849).

Comment: well, I don't know that much about vfx, so I'm not sure I can help.