Shadow Catcher not catching shadows from Node-based Emission
So apparently Shadow Catchers are only catching shadows cast by Lights(Area Lights, Sun etc.)
But if I use An Emission Shader on an object, the shadows cast by it are not caught by the Catcher.
Is there a way to make Shadow Catcher catch shadows cast by Emission node/ Emission in Shader nodes?
Thank you.

Same question here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164080/emision-catcher-for-blender, it doesn't have a full answer but guidelines in the comments.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/321890/vfx-explosions-and-shadowcatchers https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164080/emision-catcher-for-blender

How exactly did you set up your scene? What makes you think the Shadow Catcher would not catch shadows of an emission shader? In this image the right pole has a bright emissive shader, the pole on the left throws a shadow from this emission which is catched by the shadow catcher plane below which I used to create a light/shadow overlay on a blue background: shadow catcher with emission.
