Casting virtual light in live action footage
When I want to add a 3d object to a live footage or an image, and say that object is glowing. How can I render only the ligh (just like shadow catcher where we can render shadows only) so I can use it in composition.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/140460/30849

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140460/is-there-a-way-to-utilize-emissions-in-vfx https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/321890/vfx-explosions-and-shadowcatchers https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164080/emision-catcher-for-blender
