# How to match live action footage to a cg double

Tags: texturing

[image]

Hi I'm trying to match the colour of my filmed footage in my scene (right) to what the colour should be as shown by my 3d model of the same suit (left). The red obviously needs to be more pink and saturated and the blue a little more yellow but i cant figure out how to do it with hue/sat/val node or rgb curves. Any ideas on how to do that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Rather than matching the footage to the CG, match the CG to the footage.

Try using a Color Balance or Hue/Saturation node on the rendered image in the compositor before you mix it with the real footage (if your plan to do that.)

Or try adjusting the material in the Shader Editor.

Comment: That's a good suggestion but if i can I'd prefer to get everything working in the 3d scene as at the moment I'm hopeless at compositing. Any idea on how to composite two shots together?

Comment: Find a tutorial (there's tons of them), or look at this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140460/is-there-a-way-to-utilize-emissions-in-vfx