VFX explosions and shadowcatchers
I'm attempting to render an explosion to be composited into live action. The explosion is made using Blender's smoke simulation with an emissive volume shader as described in tutorials like this one. I want the light of the explosion to be cast on the live-action walls but have not found a good way to do this.  I'm hoping someone here has a clever solution or can point to an incorrect conclusion.  So far my impression is:

Cycles shadowcatchers do not catch light from emissive volumes, only from emissive meshes and regular lights
Eevee emission can be captured for use with an Eevee-style shadow catcher like the one described in this tutorial), using a light probe, but this isn't practical for animated sequences since you'd have to recalculate the light probe every frame, and anyways it doesn't seem to work for emission from volume shaders
Eevee Next (Eevee in Blender 4.2) can capture emissive surfaces using its new Global Illumination!  But I haven't gotten this to work with emissive volumes, only emissive surfaces, so I have the feeling emissive volumes are not supported yet.

I have dabbled with trying to use Geometry Nodes Volume-to-Mesh to convert my simulated explosion to a mesh surface that I could use to cast emissive light, but it seems like Geometry Nodes does not yet have access to fluid/gas simulation volume data yet.
So far my best solution is to use Cycles to cast light onto a regular (non-shadowcatcher) surface and then I'll composite that onto the live footage with an Add instead of a Multiply.  Curious to know if anyone has any other clever solutions, or if I've missed anything in the thwarting limitations listed above.

Shadow catchers don't really catch light, it catches the difference between white and the surface. Meaning it catches tints and shadows. I think you would have to render a projected version of the shot, so no use of the original footage besides as a texture. Not sure though.

This question is similar to: Is there a way to utilize emissions in VFX?. Basically, use layers and render different layers and combine them using the compositor

Why do you think the Shadow Catcher does not catch emissive lights in Cycles? You have to use it as a pass in the Compositor, not directly in the render. Here is plane as shadow catcher below a cube which has a bright red emission. The shadow catcher pass multiplied with a background image lights up the background with the red emission where the shadow catcher plane is lit by the cube: emissive light catcher

To clarify my initial question, it seems that Blender's shadow catcher does not catch emissive light from vdb volumes only, and that is my issue.  I've updated the question for clarity.
This is indeed a duplicate question and a solution is described here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140460/is-there-a-way-to-utilize-emissions-in-vfx
A clever alternative solution, given in the context of Embergen but applies to other volume emission compositing scenarios, is given at the end of this YouTube.
